# Unix Domain Sockets: Guarantees

Tags: sockets, unix

I have a program which needs to send data to another process. This will be a multiple writer one consumer setup. I do not need to support writer and consumer on different machines, so some IPC is sufficient.

**The tool is supposed to record infos I can use in debugging. That means if the writer crashes (e.g. segfault, assertion error, ...) I need to have all info that was written before the crash.**

- I initially planned to use ZeroMQ, but ZeroMQ caches in the writer before sending, so I sometimes lost data on crashes.
- So I tried to work with shared memory. No data losses here (it works perfectly), but it is extremely slow. That is definitely due to my implementation. I guess a more skilled programmer would be capable of making this blazingly fast.
- I think that unix domain sockets would be a reasonable thing to use. They should be compatible with my skills as a programmer and deliver good enough performance. **Do they guarantee no data loss on crashes of the writer?**